# onResume not working with Thread timer

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

What i am trying to do is getting `getIntent();` in onResume. all thing is happening in MainActivity only

Here is my Code but its not working  nothing is working

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    Thread timer = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                sleep(3000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                Intent intent = getIntent();
                String restaurant_name = intent.getStringExtra("restaurant_name");
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, restaurant_name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                if (restaurant_name != null) {
                    if (restaurant_name.equals("Romys")) {
                        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(26.89209, 75.82759), 15.0f));
                        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                .position(new LatLng(26.89553, 75.82842))
                                .title("ROMYS"))
                                .showInfoWindow();


                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "It was not", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
    };
    timer.start();

    super.onResume();
}
```

I tried `onResume` `onNewInent` but app is crashing.

Comment: Can you post what error are you getting from logcat?

Comment: @noidea3p5  sir i am not getting any error also .. it not evening displaying a toast also

Comment: What actually i am doing is i am sending intent from my ListView class ..And i am showing all the date  in AlertBox its all shoing in  MainActivity  so after clicking the holder alertbox disappear and again mainActivity starts so on that i want to get that intent and run my map.animateCamera

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if that is all but you are trying to do a `Toast` on a thread that is not the main UI thread. So, try to replace your toasts like:

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, restaurant_name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

with code to run it on the main UI thread:

```
    MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, restaurant_name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: I am glad i could help :)